# Supply ObjectDataSource with custom list/collection to load

Tags: c#, asp.net, objectdatasource

I know from experience that a LinqDataSource has a selecting event where we can supply our own data by assigning it to r.Result

I'm looking for the same behavior for ObjectDataSource. Although i implemented a GetAllData() method within my custom class: `SystemSettingList : List<SystemSetting>`

NOw, maybe I'm not thinking clearly here but the GetAllData is a method within my SystemSettingList class that I have to instantiate on my page later down the line in page load. How will I tell my ObjectDataSource to fetch from **that** object?

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `SelectMethod` and `TypeName`. Something like this:

```
    <asp:objectdatasource
      id="ObjectDataSource1"
      runat="server"
      selectmethod="GetAllData"
      typename="YourNamespace.SystemSettingList" />
```

Comment: How'd this great an instance of SystemSettingList? When will i be able to add the only single default record of SystemSetting to the instance?

Comment: @HassanGulzar: this get records from method "GetAllData", this is an automatic approach, you don't have to do anything else. I might be misunderstand what you're looking for

Comment: Ok. Let me try first. My concern really was that the ObjectDataSource understands the schema of the Collection Object and the single record. It generates columns and/or fields but runtime, the collection object must be initialized and must have records as well. If the collection object is not initialized (unless it automatically is), how would the GetAllData() method be called? I believe you may be right and I'm just paranoid. Thats why i'm on my PC again and about to attempt.